# Notion of rank for modules with torsion

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, modules

Is there a definition of rank (or something similar) for modules with torsion?

For instance $M=\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}_2$ considered as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module, is rank (or any other similar concept) defined for $M$?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A$ is a domain and $M$ is an $A$-module, one typically defines its rank as follows: let $K$ be the field of fractions of $A$, and let the rank of $M$ be the dimension of $M \otimes_A K$, as a vector space over $K$.

In examples such as $\mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb Z_2$, this corresponds to dropping the torsion components, since $$ (\mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb Z_2) \otimes \mathbb Q = (\mathbb Z \otimes \mathbb Q) \oplus (\mathbb Z_2 \otimes \mathbb Q) = \mathbb Q.$$

Comment: Thanks. Is there a name for the above process?

Comment: @yoyostein I haven't seen it given a name other than "rank", and my guess at why is that it makes sense only over integral domains, where things are pretty nice - and other notions of rank such as in rschwieb's reply are for modules over uglier rings, where we need to be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of different things to use like rank.

Perhaps [uniform dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_module) or Goldie reduced rank will be of use to you. Maybe [global dimension or weak global dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_dimension) too.

All of these should be applicable or any module over any ring, excepting the reduced rank, I think. I can't recall off the top of my head